# "Currency" style set for a range in Excel VBA turn out as "Accounting"

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I got the following snippet of code in a Function which is supposed to set the data body range of many columns in an Excel table to the "Currency" format:

```
For i = 5 To oActiveTable.ListColumns.count
    With oActiveTable.ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange
        ' .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 €"
        ' .NumberFormat = "Currency"
        .Style = "Currency"
    End With
Next
```

The commented lines are the unsatisfactory or borken attempts, respectively.

`.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 €"` works, but causes the format to show up as "Custom" This is undesired, as it may cause people building on top of my approach to continue this bad practice.

`.NumberFormat = "Currency"` doesn't work (error 1004 - obvious, in hindsight), some digging around in docs, tutorials and articles showed that "Currency" is actually a cell style.

`.Style = "Currency"` works, i.e. a style is set, but somehow becomes the "Accounting" style - which is not what I want, as we do not want the "- €" for 0 (zero) values.

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to be stumped by this, but searching for it didn't turn up much - most people seem to resort to setting number formats directly.

I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7. Both are set to English for the UI language, but the systems has its regional settings (time, date, number formats, ...) set to Germany.

**Edit:**
At least the confusing aspect on my part is solved: the Currency **style** has the Accounting **number format** assigned.

Comment: Currency ist just a synonym for a list of formats. Here my "currency" default is `#,##0.00 [$€-407];[RED]-#,##0.00 [$€-407]`. I wouldn't be too concerned about the "Custom" name.

Comment: Unfortunately, the recipients of the files created this way are kinda picky :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is reading out what "Currency" format means for Excel and then set the format. Select a cell with the "Currency" format and do this in the VBA editor:

```
Debug.Print Application.ActiveCell.NumberFormatLocal
```

Output (on my machine):

```
#.##0,00 €
```

Now select the target cell (or select a range in you macro, whatever you need) and do this (I'm sticking with a active cell as it is easy to test):

Application.ActiveCell.NumberFormatLocal = "#.##0,00 €"

If you check the UI, it should show up as "Currency" format.

Comment: Yeah, seems like this is the only way... grmbl. Someone please give me a spreadsheet application with more UI/API consistency :P

Comment: I normally resort to digging into the xml files in the Excel bundle file and search for IDs and names. That way I found out that there is no "currency". And yes, you are right: Excel is inconsistent between UI and API. A lot!:-)